# Is there a way ksql to set the primary key explicitly while joining two tables?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Have three tables tbl1, tbl2 and tbl3 with primary key id2, id2 and id3 respectively. After  full outer join of tbl1 and tbl2 is there way to set id3 as PK for the newly created tables.

```
create table tbl12 as select * from tbl1 full outer join tbl2 on tbl1.id2=tbl2.id2 emit changes;
```

Here im getting id2 as PK. I need to set the PK as id3 so that full outer join with tbl3 is possible.

Comment: Is there a column in tbl1 or tbl2 which has the value of id3?

Comment: Yes tbl2 contains id3 in it.

Comment: Have you tried using partition by?

Comment: Exception while preparing statement: Line: 1, Col: 285: Column 'final_id' is ambiguous. Getting error if i use partition by in above select command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ksqlDB uses the first table's key as the key for the output schema.

This would mean that you start your query with
`create table outputTable as select * from tbl3 ...`

Comment: This won't work with my scenario, But appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry to hear that this won't help.  Can you say why it isn't working in your case?  Also, if there's an issue/bug/limitation in ksqlDB, it may be worth opening a GitHub issue and discussing a fix there!

Comment: Consider case with three id's. ID1, ID2 & ID3. ID1 table has reference to ID2. 
ID2 table has reference to ID3. We need to combine all three into a single table using a full outer join.